# Change style in Typescript when item loads

Tags: html, angular, typescript

For example, let's say I have a list, and and an array with the datas.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <div *ngFor="let data of exampleArray">
        <li id="createId(...)" class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row">
                 CONTENT
              </div>                 
         </li>
     </div>
</ul>
```

And the **array**:

```
exampleArray = [{name:"A", type:"1"},{name:"B", type:"0"}...]
```

`Type`represents the **background color** of the item. **(1 -> green, 0 -> white, -1 -> red)**

I only want to display the 'names' in rows.
Question is, how can I make **something like an onLoad function** for these, so when I open the page, and it loads the names, the items will automatically get their type of styling.
Each item in the `li` has a unique id.

Comment: you not using ngStyle or ngClass for styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ngClass for setting classes for you items dynamically based on item type:

in template:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <div *ngFor="let data of exampleArray">
        <li class="list-group-item">
              <div class="row" [ngClass]="'type' + data.type">
                 {{data.name}}
              </div>                 
        </li>
     </div>
</ul>
```

array:

```
exampleArray = [{name:"A", type:"1"},{name:"B", type:"0"}, {name:"C", type:"-1"}]
```

css:

```
.type1{
  background-color: green
}
.type0{
  background-color: white
}
.type-1{
  background-color: red
}
```

working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cka7uh)